# Conversion of disk image from Encase (E01) to Raw format

Tags: command-line, file-format, conversion, disk-image, format-conversion

I am trying to convert from EnCase to Raw format using instructions given on this [page](http://digitalcorpora.org/corpora/disk-images/format-conversion).

The following takes place:

```
manu@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ ewfexport nps-2010-emails.E01 
The program 'ewfexport' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install ewf-tools
manu@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install ewf-tools
[sudo] password for manu: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ewf-tools
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 503 not upgraded.
Need to get 162 kB of archives.
After this operation, 438 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/universe ewf-tools amd64 20100226-1build2 [162 kB]
Fetched 162 kB in 2s (65.7 kB/s)    
Selecting previously unselected package ewf-tools.
(Reading database ... 158500 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking ewf-tools (from .../ewf-tools_20100226-1build2_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up ewf-tools (20100226-1build2) ...
manu@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ ewfexport nps-2010-emails.E01 
ewfexport 20100226 (libewf 20100226, libuna 20091031, libbfio 20091114, zlib 1.2.3.4, libcrypto 1.0.0, libuuid)

Information for export required, please provide the necessary input
Export to file format (raw, ewf, smart, ftk, encase1, encase2, encase3, encase4, encase5, encase6, linen5, linen6, ewfx) [raw]: raw
Target path and filename with extension or - for stdout: /user/manu/Downloads nps
Start export at offset (0 >= value >= 10485760) [0]: 0
Amount of bytes to export (0 >= value >= 10485760) [10485760]: 

Export started at: Fri Jun 13 02:54:12 2014

This could take a while.

Unable to open output.
export_handle_open_output: unable to open file: /user/manu/Downloads nps.
```

I had to copy and paste from the terminal,as I am a newbie,I am not allowed to post more than two links or any pictures. This question is very important as it is required for the summer intern I am currently pursuing.

Please help me to understand the intermediate prompt messages and to convert the file from ***EnCase*** to ***Raw*** format.
The Digital Corpus (The EnCase file) is downloaded from [Digital Corpora](http://digitalcorpora.org/corpora/disk-images).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem should be clear from the message

```
export_handle_open_output: unable to open file: /user/manu/Downloads nps.
```

i.e. the path and/or filename that you have specified is not valid. First, are you sure your home directory is under `/user`? The standard Linux location would be `/home` (although that may be different if you are in a corporate environment), so that if you are trying to save the raw file as `nps` in your own Downloads directory the full path and filename with extension will probably be something like `/home/manu/Downloads/nps`.

*[The wording of the prompt is unclear, but it appears to actually require a single contiguous `target/path/to/filename.ext`, not a whitespace separated list like `target/path/to` `file` `ext`]*

Or since you are running the `ewfexport` file from that directory, you can just use `.` to indicate the current directory i.e.

```
Target path and filename with extension or - for stdout: ./nps
```

although personally I would probably use something like `./nps-2010-emails.raw` to make the image's origin more obvious, i.e.

```
Target path and filename with extension or - for stdout: ./nps-2010-emails.raw
```

Comment: thanx, I corrected that but i still did not get what is meant by

***Start export at offset (0 >= value >= 10485760) [0]:***

 and  ***Amount of bytes to export (0 >= value >= 10485760) [10485760]:*** what answer am I suppose to give to the above questions ?

Comment: You should really ask your supervisor about that - although I expect you can just accept the default values (which will probably convert the whole image).